# Show active class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add class 'active' to next div 1 second before first is removed.

Practically, I want to have an 'active' class on 2 elements at the same time for that 1 second.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

```
<div class="map-inner">
    <div class="map-location-outer">
        <div class="map-location-inner location1 active">
            <div class="map-location">
                <div class="map-icon">
                    <img src="i/content/map-icon2.svg">
                </div>
                <span class="map-pin"><span></span></span>
            </div><!-- map-location -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="map-location-outer">
        <div class="map-location-inner location2">
            <div class="map-location">
                <div class="map-icon">
                    <img src="i/content/map-icon3.svg">
                </div>
                <span class="map-pin"><span></span></span>
            </div><!-- map-location -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="map-location-outer">
        <div class="map-location-inner location3">
            <div class="map-location">
                <div class="map-icon">
                    <img src="i/content/map-icon1.png">
                </div>
                <span class="map-pin"><span></span></span>
            </div><!-- map-location -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var x = 1;

function updateClass() {
    let a = $(".map-location-inner.active");
    a.removeClass("active");
    a = a.parent().next(".map-location-outer");
    if (a.length == 0)
        a = $(".map-location-outer").first();
    a.find(".map-location-inner").addClass("active");
}

setInterval(function () {
    updateClass();
}, x * 5500);
```

Comment: I haven't looked at the code but the basic logic is, add the new active class, set a timeout for 1 second then remove the old active class

Comment: @Greg I added HTML to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to wait before removing 1<sup>st</sup> `.active` class and add 2<sup>nd</sup> `.active` class before removing 1<sup>st</sup> one.

```
var x = 1;

function updateClass() {
    let a = $(".map-location-inner.active");
    let b = a.parent().next(".map-location-outer");
    if (b.length == 0)
        b = $(".map-location-outer").first();
    b.find(".map-location-inner").addClass("active");

    setTimeout(function() {
        a.removeClass("active");
    }, 1000);
}

setInterval(function () {
    updateClass();
}, x * 5500);
```

Comment: This totally helped me. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Comment: Do you know how to animate that 'removeClass'? I want it to have something like fadeOut effect

Comment: Just add this css to your stylesheet  `.map-location-inner{ transition: all 1s ease-out; }`

Comment: If you need more custom animation, then you should use GSAP( https://greensock.com) or jQuery `toggleClass` and add your custom animation with new (toggled) class.